# Flip transition in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am facing problems in flipping views in iPhone.

I have two views in appDelegate. I want to flip them once user clicks on a button.

I have the following code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];

transition.duration = 0.75;
[transition @"twist"];
[transition setSubtype:@"fromRight"];

transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[transition setFillMode:@"extended"];

[[window layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


[window addSubview:self.s.view];
[CATransaction commit];
```

But this is not working. Do anybody knows a better way to flip the views on window side.

What I am doing is calling the method from appDelegate in the respective viewControllers to flip the views.

Comment: [transition @"twist"]; <- is that a mistake? What is that doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [The Elements](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TheElements/index.html) sample code. Particularly [AtomicElementViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Listings/Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419-Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10) `-flipCurrentView`.

Comment: Only Instead of content view you need to add window as follows:

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];

if You dont want to use content view and do it on window side.

Comment: I'm curious why you would do it with the window itself? That's a very unusual approach; generally you use the contentView of the window and leave the window alone.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using the 3.0 SDK and all you want is a simple flip transition (ala the Weather app) then you don't need to go down to `CATransition`. The higher-level `UIView` animation transitions will do what you want but with 3.0 there is an even easier way: simply present your new view as a modal view controller and set the modal transition style to flip. From within the first controller:

```
UIViewController *controllerForSecondView = ..;
controllerForSecondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controllerForSecondView animated:YES];
```

Flip back again by using `dismissModalViewController`.

[Documentation Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyle)

Comment: Thanks for the great tip!
NB to anyone reading: as per Jared's answer, the setting should be set on 'controllerForSecondView', not 'self'.

Comment: Quite right, I should have edited this ages ago when Jared first posted his answer. I've now corrected this.

Answer (score 5):

@Luke - thanks, this sample helped me...1 correction though (based on UIViewController.h)

```
UIViewController *controllerForSecondView = ..;
controllerForSecondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controllerForSecondView animated:YES];
```

From the header file comments:

// Defines the transition style that will be used for this view controller when it is presented modally. Set this property **on the view controller to be presented, not the presenter.**
// Defaults to UIModalTransitionStyleSlideVertical.
@property(nonatomic,assign) UIModalTransitionStyle modalTransitionStyle

Comment: Well spotted! I must have missed that, but thats what you get when you don't actually run the code you are writing ;)