# Image Animation. Rotate Image like a coin rotation

Tags: ios, animation, rotation

I have a situation where I have to rotate the image like a coin. I am doing as follows.

```
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
  transition.startProgress = 0;
   transition.endProgress = 1.0;
  transition.type = @"flip";
  transition.subtype = @"fromRight";
  transition.duration = 1.0;
  transition.repeatCount = 15;

   [rotateimageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
```

It is rotating the image but it is not completely rotating it Please check the video.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4t2aqyscgecqfb/animationVideo.mov?dl=0

It looks like rotating but the right pointing arrow never points left. I want it to point left and right as a complete coin animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flip transition in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227841/flip-transition-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following article in which I explained how to rotate a banner. Maybe you can apply the same techniques in your application.

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/876_Creating_a_Flipping_Tweets_View.aspx

-

```
(void) updateFlippingView:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    if(index == ([tweets count] -1))
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    UILabel *messageLabel = (UILabel *) [flippingView viewWithTag:MESSAGE_LABEL_TAG];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

            [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
                messageLabel.alpha = 0.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    messageLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    messageLabel.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:index];
                }];

            }];

        flippingView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotationIndex *M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

       for(UIView *subView in flippingView.subviews)
            {
                subView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotationIndex *M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            }

        }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           rotationIndex = rotationIndex == 1 ? 2 :1;

        }];

    index++;

}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon, because if the link breaks the answer is useless. You should include the essential parts of the solution in your answer itself.